# Fill the colour using UITouchEvent in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used the code as:-

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event

{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:_alphabetBackgroundImageView];

   if((location.x > 50 && location.x < _alphabetBackgroundImageView.frame.size.width-50) && (location.y > 50 && location.y < _alphabetBackgroundImageView.frame.size.height-50))

   {

        UIImageView *lineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];

        lineImageView.center = location;

        lineImageView.backgroundColor = selectedColor;

        [_alphabetBackgroundImageView addSubview:lineImageView];

   }

}



- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event

{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:_alphabetBackgroundImageView];

    if((location.x > 50 && location.x < _alphabetBackgroundImageView.frame.size.width-50) && (location.y > 50 && location.y < _alphabetBackgroundImageView.frame.size.height-50))
    {

        UIImageView *lineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];

        lineImageView.center = location;

        lineImageView.backgroundColor = selectedColor;

        [_alphabetBackgroundImageView addSubview:lineImageView];

    }

}



- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:_alphabetBackgroundImageView];




   if((location.x > 50 && location.x < _alphabetBackgroundImageView.frame.size.width-50) && (location.y > 50 && location.y < _alphabetBackgroundImageView .frame.size.height-50))
    {

        UIImageView *lineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];

        lineImageView.center = location;

        lineImageView.backgroundColor = selectedColor;

        [_alphabetBackgroundImageView addSubview:lineImageView];


    }

}
```

IN .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *alphabetBackgroundImageView;
```

In .m file:-

```
alphabetsStoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"write a.png",@"write b.png",@"write c.png",@"write d.png",@"write e.png",@"write f.png",@"write g.png",@"write h.png",@"write i.png",@"write j.png",@"write k.png",@"write l.png",@"write m.png",@"write n.png",@"write o.png",@"write p.png",@"write q.png",@"write r.png",@"write s.png",@"write t.png",@"write u.png",@"write v.png",@"write w.png",@"write x.png",@"write y.png",@"write z.png", nil];

 selectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:181/255.0 green:218/255.0 blue:234/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

I have used two UIImageView AND this 2 images are placed on the same location .location at:-x=492.5;y=323;width=500;height=500.

one image to display the image and other to change the image.

The image displaying is letters from A-Z.
I have used UITouch event.So when the letter displaying i call the touch event.To display the next letter .

I have used a button to show the next.So when i click the next button the letter will change.

i have used colour as named selectedColor in code.so i can fill the colour in the letter.

But i need to the condition that if the colour fully not filled then show alert.HOW TO DO?

Comment: i need to fill the color.how to do

Answer (score 0):

By using the Below code, you can get the background colour of the imageview.

```
UIColor *imageviewOneColor = yourImageviewOne.backgroundColor;
UIColor *imageviewTwoColor = yourImageviewTwo.backgroundColor;
```

So you can try this below code to check whether the two image background colour are same or not.

```
if([imageviewOneColor isEqual: imageviewTwoColor]){

    NSLog(@"same colour");

}else{

    NSLog(@"Different colour");

    your alert - As folows
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you just typed this up on mobile or something, but your style is pretty "wrong" in Obj-C conventions. use `camelCase` for variable names and the pointer before the var name like `UIColor *imageOneColor = ...`. Following conventions will make it easier for other programmers to understand your code! :D